# Let $D$ be an algebraic number ring of an algebraic number field and $A$ be any ideal in $D$. Could we state that $A \ne 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> **My question:** Let $D$ be an algebraic number ring of an algebraic number field and $A$ be any ideal in $D$. Could we state that $A \ne 0$?

If you answer my question, please give me an example to see the truth. Thank all!

Comment: An ideal is at least an additive subgroup. Since a group has an identity element, it is definitely not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Any ring $R$ has the structure of an Abelian group with $(R,+)$. As part of the definition of an ideal $I$ of $R$, $I$ is required to be a subgroup of $R$. In particular, $0\in I$. So, an ideal can never be empty.

**Edit:** (In response to the question's edit.) Actually it is true that in a field $k$, the only ideals are the unit ideal $(1)=k$ and the zero ideal $(0)=0$. This is because if $\frak{a}$ is an ideal of $k$ and $x\in \frak{a}$ and $x\ne 0$, then $1=x^{-1}\cdot x\in \frak{a}$, so $\frak{a}=(1)$. So, the only nonzero ideal in a field is the whole field itself. I.e. the only proper ideal is the zero ideal.

Comment: That's was my mistake. I have edited my question. Sorry! Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

Question doesn't make much sense. In any ring $R$, $(0) = \{0\}$ is an ideal.

In a field $F$, there are two ideals: $\{0\}$ and $F$.